# React white page when fetching as google SEO

Tags: reactjs, prerender

I have been trying many things on my React app to be SEO friendly, unfortunately, I just see a white page without any results .. here is what I have tried:

(PS: I am actually building my app locally and checking the result using phantomjs.)

1 - Using different polyfills at the very top of my app such as

```
import 'es5-shim';
import 'es6-shim'; 

import 'babel-polyfill';
import 'url-search-params-polyfill';
import 'whatwg-fetch';
```

2 - Disable all XHR calls from my APP.

3 - Trying to simplify the app as much as possible such as

```
ReactDOM.render(<div>Hello, World!</div>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

**Here things work well**, in my phantomjs result I see the image with the Hello, World!

Now every time I import my Root component back in the ReactDOM.render, I get the white page again.

I am out of ideas, I thought of maybe transforming my app into an SSR app but I really would like to know if this is doable without it. It sounds like my Root component might be too "heavy" to be able to be rendered on time.

Any ideas on which I could spend some time on ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use Chrome instead of phantomjs to test your pages. At Prerender.io, we've seen lots of cases where phantomjs cannot render newer websites and just shows a blank page, so we use Headless Chrome to render websites and it works great!